# Pandas to_sql Trying to Index Nullable Column

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to set up a job that dumps data into a SQL table every day, overwriting the existing data.

```
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='dbo', 
          index=True, index_label='IdColumn', 
          if_exists='replace')
```

However behind the scenes SQLAlchemy is trying to create the table with IdColumn VARCHAR(max), and being nullable. So SQL throws an error when it tries to create the index.

It's pretty trivial to truncate the table before I write the data to it, but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the write the index to the sql table as a normal column, you can do a `reset_index` before the `to_sql` call:

```
df.reset_index().to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='dbo', index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

The only problem is the name of that column, if you want a custom one you first have to set the index name (`df.index.name = 'IdColumn'`) or rename after the reset_index.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [dtype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) argument which takes a dictionary mapping data frame column names to specified [sqlalchemy data types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_5/reference/sqlalchemy/types.html). You can try `Varchar`:

```
import sqlalchemy

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='dbo', 
          index=True, index_label='IdColumn', 
          if_exists='replace',
          dtype={'IdColumn': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})
```

or generic `String` type, specifying a length:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import String

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='dbo', 
          index=True, index_label='IdColumn', 
          if_exists='replace',
          dtype={'IdColumn': String(length=255)})
```

Comment: I just tried this type of approach for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64993374/2144390) but I found that `dtype` does not seem to affect the `index` column (even if we give it an explicit `index_label`), only the "real" data columns.