# Mysql index without key specification on replace?

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
mytable.to_sql(name='mytable', con=engine, index=True, if_exists='replace')
```

But it keeps throwing the following error:

```
'(1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'index' used in key specification without a key length")'[SQL: CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_index ON mytable (index)]
```

I think I understand why the error happens but in the context for the code above I don't know how to specify the length. I can't change the underlying database since this code was handed down to me.

Comment: @snakecharmerb How would I do that? I know you could use params but what would the index length param look like?

Comment: Something like ```index_label='`index`(1000)'``` ?

Comment: Seems like a good idea but can't get the formatting to work. Still throws the same error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34515714/2144390 - Your DataFrame appears to have a string `index` that is being translated into a TEXT (a.k.a. CLOB) column which is not suitable for a CREATE INDEX statement in MySQL (or most other databases).

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you this helped a lot. Anyway to stop pandas/dataframe from being a string?

Comment: @Max - Take a look at how the DataFrame is being created. Perhaps it actually has a numeric column that is being cast to string because it it too big for the default (integer) conversions that pandas uses.